# Vue: How do I wait for a Promise in the component initialization process?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have several Vue components (realized as `.vue` files process by Webpack & the Vue Loader) that need to be synchronized (i.e. display / allow interaction of a video stream). Some of them require some initialization effort (i.e. downloading meta data or images).

Can I somehow *delay* a component until that initialization is ready? Perfect would be if I could wait for a Promise to be fulfilled in a lifecycle hook like `beforeCreate`.

I know about asynchronous components, but as far as I understand all I could do is to lazy-load that component, and I still would have a way to wait for a certain initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that on route level.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        doSomeRequests()
         .then(() => (next()))
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

`doSomeRequests` is a function that is doing some async code. When that async code finish
then you call `next()` to allow vue router to enter the component which corresponds to the url. In the example the component `Foo`

> My suggestion would be to show a loader in the component.

```
<template>
  <!-- code  -->
    <LoaderComponent :loading="loading" />
  <!-- code  -->
</template>
```

And the script part:

```
<script>
 export default {
   // code
   data: () => ({
    loading: false
   }),

   created () {
     this.loading = true
     doSomeRequests()
      .then(<!-- code  -->)
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false))
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm not using the Router right now (just a single page), but good to know there is a way. I would need to decouple the initialization logic from the component so it can be called here, do you know of any way to have in defiend with the component itself (no matter if the Router is used)?

Comment: You can either use my suggestion about showing a loader, or on the parent component you can do the requests and when those finish you can show the component. Basically with `v-if="requestsFinished"`

Comment: I don't know who gave you a downvote but he didn't commented why. So I am gonna upvote since I don't see any reason for downvoting.